# 日本語に違和感: 関連サイト

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

質問ページの右サイドバーにあるセクション:

[image: 関連サイト]

違和感がある点:

- 質問の一覧なので、「サイト」はおかしい

Answer (score 1):

- 関連する質問

Comment: 「関連する質問」はどうですかね？

Comment: @tomute 「する」の方が舌になじむ気がしますね。回答を変更しました